# Ubuntu Screenshot Window Class

Tags: compiz, window-manager, screenshot, animations

I would like to know the class for the "thing" that pops up when you take a screen shot using the default screen capture utility in Ubuntu 12.04. When I do a full screen capture it lags a lot because of particular animation I use to open things like drop down menus. Therefore I’d like to disable that only.

If someone could provide me with the window "class=" or however I would disable the animation there it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a terminal and enter `xwininfo`, then you can click a window and information about that window will be printed to the terminal.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to have found the object which I need but is a valid class "Class: InputOutput"? I set up a new animation for that particular window class in compiz but the animation doesn't change when I screen shot. Still the beam up effect (from compiz extra)

Comment: *That is useful but when I try to click on the "popup" it simply clicks on whatever is behind it as if it is transparent.